# Why does nodeeclipse require a monitor path to run?

Tags: eclipse, nodeclipse

When i press Run as node application,

Node.js monitor is not correctly configured. 
Select path to installed util: forever, node-dev, nodemon or supervisor.
Please goto Windows > Preferences > nodeclipse  and configure the correct location.

I have now installed nodemon and everything works fine.

But, yesterday i ran my node apps with no issues or monitors, why am I suddenly forced to use one?

Given that (Run as Node application) and (Run as Node with monitor) are separate options for Run, why do they both require monitors? I am new to eclipse, so don't hesitate to offer obvious answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was unsolved issue, that Eclipse can use only one Run configuration.

To clean up

1. Right-click .js file, select Properties
2. on Run/Debug Setting page delete all but 1 run configuration